# Opencart string and charachter count script How rewrite that

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, counter

I'm trying to add a character count to my opencart product form. The problem is it's not working because of the opencart string which seems not to be accepted by java. How do I adapt that properly?

```
<?php $h2_input_name = "product_description[". $language['language_id']. "][prod_h2]" ;?>
```

Which echo's --> product_description[1][prod_h2]

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>
<form name="myform">
<input name="<?php echo $h2_input_name ?>" type="text" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.<?php echo $h2_input_name ?>,this.form.countdown,15);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.<?php echo $h2_input_name ?>,this.form.countdown,15);" maxlength="15"><br>
<font size="1">(Maximum characters: 15)<br>
You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="15"> characters left.</font>
</form>
```

For some reason product_description[1][prod_h2] won't work. If i use product_description it works fine.

How should or can i rewrite product_description[1][prod_h2] so the counter works?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
this.form.<?php echo $h2_input_name ?>
```

to

```
this.form.elements["<?php echo $h2_input_name ?>"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works that way for limiting the input itself. Only the counter doesn't count down or up. It works if  its done this way <form name="myform">
<input name="limitedtextfield" type="text" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,15);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,15);" maxlength="15"><br>
<font size="1">(Maximum characters: 15)<br>
You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="15"> characters left.</font>
</form>